# Scaling CardView hides the elevation shadow

Tags: android, android-cardview

Check out these images:
**Before scaling**
[image]

**After scaling**

[image]

My problem is, the CardView does scale, but hides the shadow of the card View. Any suggestions/ideas.

**Edit:**

After adding **app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"** nothing changes
[image]

cardUseCompatPadding just handles shadow size between different API versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line to your CardView in XML.

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

**UPDATE**

As i noticed in your second image which is labeled after scaling, your binds are on image view. So that image view is being stretched and overlayed your card view. You can see the shadows of cardview which is at the behind. You need to define binds on CardView and let the ImageView fill the blanks in CardView by giving it match parent to layout attributes.

Comment: Does not help. Same behavior

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's the intended behaviour. We can see you have a `FrameLayout` inside, maybe you stretch that one instead? Since the `CardView` `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content`, it will wrap the stretched view and you still will have your shadow.

Comment: It just scales content within card boundary, CardView boundaries remain intact and do not scale. So this does not help. What I want is CardView should scale along with shadow.